# Which version of rails to require a lesser version of RubyGems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mongrel

I'm unable to update RubyGems because of shared hosting, but can change versions of rails quite easily.

I get the following error when I try to start mongrel:

```
** Starting Mongrel listening at 0.0.0.0:2011
** Starting Rails with production environment...
Rails requires RubyGems >= 1.3.2 (you have 1.3.1). 
Please `gem update --system` and try again.
```

My current rails --version is 2.3.5.

Is there a version of rails I can downgrade to so that it doesn't require 1.3.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Rails 2.3.2 is released on March 15, 2009
- Rails 2.3.3 is released on July 20, 2009
- Rubygems 1.3.2 is released on April 15, 2009

So Rails 2.3.2 it's compatible because rails use allways the last rubygems released